# jQuery anchor navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, anchor

I want to build a basic anchor based navigation system using jQuery.  I don't really want to use a [plugin like this](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942013/javascript-anchor-navigation).  Can anyone help me out with the basic logic of building a system like this?

Essentially I want to be able to have one page serve up multiple ajax content via links like this:

- `/myurl.html#state1`
- `/myurl.html#state2`

Currently I just bind to the click handler of links to open up dialogs etc.  I could then change the URL to `/myurl.html#state1`.  The question is do I do it this way, or do I just make the `<a>` tags themselves point to that url and then use jQuery to detect when the URL has changed meaning itll also work on page load too?

Any suggestions / thoughts would be great - thanks

Comment: I know you might not want to use a plugin, but I've found jquery-bbq to be the best for this kind of functionality http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: Sans plugin, this will be of use http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/creating-ajax-websites-based-on-anchor-navigation/

Comment: @Calum I spotted BBQ before, thanks for the suggestion, its just for one page though so a plugin seems like overkill.  I saw the yendesign post before as well but I really dont like the idea of setting a timer to check for changes - seems wasteful

Comment: @Chris, why re-invent the wheel?  BBQ has a small foot print and supports everything you seem to be looking for and more out of the box.

Comment: @Chris - I agree with everyone here...  Go with the plugin.

Comment: I want to do this because of two reasons: 1. This is going into an embedded system where the use of external plugins is hard to get sanctioned and footprint is an issue.  2. I want to learn :)

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn lol most people want the code copy and paste don't want to change anything, but well done for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#state1" rel="ajaxpage1.html"></a>
<a href="#state2" rel="ajaxpage2.html"></a>

$('a').each(function (i,obj){
   $(obj).click(function (){
       var url = $(obj).attr('rel');
       $..ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function (){...},
          error : function (){...}// incase you get a 404, or 500 and so on....
       });
   });
});

$(document).ready(function (){
   //if you need it on refresh, or if a user got the link from another page
   // it automatically will trigger the click therefore trigger the ajax
   if(window.location.hash != '#'){
      $('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').click();
   }
});
```

I still thing you should use a plugin, as they have had bugs, and fixed them probably so you would have to test your thing, waste alot of time but your call :)